# Some questions on Radon-Nykodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Suppose that Q and R are two probability distributions on $\Omega$ equipped with $\mathcal{F}$ sigma algebra. Moreover, suppose that $Q<<R$. By Radon-Nykodym derivative we know that there exists a signed measure $f$ such that $$Q(A)=\int_{A}fdR, \forall A\in \mathcal{F}.$$

Since $Q$ is nonnegative, we can conclude that f is nonnegative $R$ a.e. My question is related to the well definedness of KL-divergence which is $$\mathbb{E}^{Q}[\log{\frac{dQ}{dR}}]$$

we know that $\frac{dQ}{dR}$ is nonnegative $R$ a.e. . But here we are taking an integral with respect to $Q$. How can we show that $\frac{dQ}{dR}$ is also nonnegative $Q$ a.e. ?

Furthermore, we know that $\frac{dQ}{dR}\in L^1({R})$. How can we show that $\log{\frac{dQ}{dR}} \in L^1(Q)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We know that $dQ/dR$ is nonnegative $R$-a.e. How can we show that $dQ/dR$ is also nonnegative $Q$-a.e.?

Let $E = \{dQ/dR < 0\}$ be the set where $dQ/dR$ is negative. By definition, $R(E) = 0$. Since $Q \ll R$, $Q(E) = 0$, by definition (or one of the equivalent characterizations) of absolute continuity of measures. Hence $dQ/dR$ is nonnegative $Q$-a.e.

> Furthermore, we know $dQ/dR\in L^1(R)$. How can we show $\log(dQ/dR)\in L^1(Q)$?

It isn't always the case that $\log(dQ/dR)\in L^1(Q)$. Here is an example to illustrate. Let our space be $[1,\infty)$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and
$$
R(dx) = \frac{dx}{x^2(\log x)^2},\quad Q(dx) = \frac{dx}{x(\log x)^2}.
$$
It's straightforward to check that both $R$ and $Q$ are finite measures on $[1,\infty)$, and that $Q\ll R$ with $dQ/dR = x$. We compute
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E^Q[\log\frac{dQ}{dR}] &:= \int_{1}^\infty \log(x)\,Q(dx)\\
&= \int_1^\infty \log(x)\,\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^2}\\
&=\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x(\log x)} \stackrel{u=\log x}{=} \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{u} = \infty,
\end{align*}
so $\log(dQ/dR)\notin L^1(Q)$.

Comment: if $log(dQ/dR)$ does not belong to $L^1(Q)$, how can we define the KL-divergence which is integral of $log(dQ/dR)$ with respect to Q?

Comment: @S_Alex: It may not always be defined, as the example illustrates. On Wikipedia (at https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#/Definition), for instance, you'll see the disclaimer attached to the definition "provided the expression exists."